# Is there xml generator from DTD(not XSD)?

Tags: xml, generator, dtd

I need some XML documents for my experiments.
I have DTD file. i searched generator using google.
 
There are many XML generator from XSD. But i was unable to find XML generator from DTD.
Is there XML generator from DTD? and i need this generator can be set parameter, such as file size. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it'll suit your needs precisely, but with [oXygen XML Editor](http://oxygenxml.com/), you can first convert a DTD file into an XSD schema file (**Tools** > **Generate/Convert Schema**) and then generate a sample XML file from that XSD schema file (**Tools** > **Generate Sample XML Files...**).

As far as I can tell, it won't allow you to control file size directly, but you can set other options (such as the number of repetitions, maximum recursion level, and so on) that directly affect file size.